# cannot use ref in function-component

Tags: typescript, react-native

I am trying to get the width of a child's component in my parent one in react:

```
import { FC, PropsWithChildren, useRef } from "react";

const MyParent: FC<PropsWithChildren> = (props) => {
    const myref = useRef(null);
    return (<MyChild ref={myref}/>)
}

const MyChild: FC<PropsWithChildren> = (props) => {
    return (<View />)
}
```

However that won't compile. I get the following error:

> Type '{ ref: MutableRefObject; }' is not assignable to type
> 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; }'.   Property 'ref'
> does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode;
> }'.ts(2322)

I thought every object could be used as a ref. How can I use a ref to my child?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `ref` is a preserved prop from react and you cannot specify it directly as props. But you can use `forwardRef` function to do so:

```
import {type PropsWithChildren, forwardRef} from "react";

const MyChild = forwardRef<View, PropsWithChildren>((props, ref) => {
    return <View ref={ref} />
})

MyChild.displayName = "MyChild";

const MyParent: FC<PropsWithChildren> = (props) => {
    const myref = useRef<View>(null);

    return (<MyChild ref={myref}/>)
}
```

You can read more in official documentation (https://react.dev/reference/react/forwardRef)

Comment: Should have mentioned, that the `div` is just a sample. Actually I'm not using react but react-native, that doesn't have `HTMLElement`s. Updating my question.

Comment: Yeap, that was it. Thank you

Comment: One last thing: how would I provide the type-info to `useRef`? I tried `useRef<MyChild>(null)` in order to have a strongly-typed ref and to get its properties wthin my parent-component accessible. But that doesn't compile either ("MyChild' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof MyChild'?ts(2749"))

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain you have to use `View` type the ref is pointing to it. so: `useRef<View>(null)`

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain added an example to the answer